# HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class org.springframeworks.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, error-handling, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-500, servletexception

```
HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class org.springframeworks.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet


type Exception report

message Error instantiating servlet class org.springframeworks.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class org.springframeworks.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1524)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1480)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframeworks.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1524)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1480)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.41 logs.**strong text**


Apache Tomcat/8.0.41
```

Logs:

SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet dispatcher
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframeworks.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:518)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:499)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:817)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1524)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1480)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Dispatcher-Servlet.xml

```
<!--  Let Front Controller know where the other controller 
allign so than i have added context Element -->
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   ">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.irk.FrontEndShoping.Controller" />

   <bean id="viewResolver" 
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />

        </bean>

   </beans>
```

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframeworks.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Page.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Online Shoping</title>
</head>
<body>  
    ${Greeting}
</body>
</html>
```

Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.irk</groupId>
    <artifactId>FrontEndShoping</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>FrontEndShoping Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <javaee.version>7.0</javaee.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- spring mvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javaee.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>FrontEndShoping</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

PageController:

```
package com.irk.FrontEndShoping.Controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/**
 * 
 * @author HP
 *
 */
@Controller
public class PageController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/home", "/index"})
    public ModelAndView getPage() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("page");
        mv.addObject("Greeting", "Hello its Greeting from Controller");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

Using:
package com.irk.FrontEndShoping.Controller;

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/**
 * 
 * @author HP
 *
 */
@Controller
public class PageController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/home", "/index"})
    public ModelAndView getPage() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("page");
        mv.addObject("Greeting", "Hello its Greeting from Controller");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

Using:

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Apache Maven 3.3.3
Apache Tomcate:  apache-tomcat-8.0.41
```

Could you please explain me Why this error is Coming 
and how to solve all the 500 error when it comes 
Kindly need some specific i have seen so many different different solution which is not working i am looking for some proper answer which should applicable for 500 errors

Comment: Looks like you have executor bean in your code which is unknown for spring.  Are you using spring scheduler?

Comment: no i am not using

Comment: Can you put your class which has all the bean??

Comment: @ZishanMohsin  i have updated question with added whole code kindly provide some solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Watch your Code with 30 minuts i have taken your code and trying to run in my local finally i found the solution : see the Given below property which you have added in to your web.xml which is not correct

```
<servlet-class>org.springframeworks.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
```

must be

```
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
```

Comment: working find i got the answer now actually web.xml was searching DispatcherServlet Class